# Updating Hyperledger Fabric peers/channels when revoking a certificate of a user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, certificate-revocation, hyperldger-fabric-peer

I am trying to implement a Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 network, on which users' certificates are going to be potentially revoked at some point in time. I am able to successfully revoke certificates and update local clients' msp with the new CRL.

I cannot find a clear workflow, to update either peers or channels with new CRLs, in order to prevent users with revoked certificates from invoking transactions.

Can somebody indicate a clear series of steps to achieve this on the test-network configuration?